# If $\{u(x,y)+v(x,y): z=x+iy\in \mathbb{C} \}$is bounded then $f$ is constant function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)= u+ iv$ where $u$, $v$ are real and imaginary parts of $f$ respectively and $f$ is entire function. If $\{u(x,y)+v(x,y): z=x+iy\in \mathbb{C} \}$is 
bounded then function is constant.

Here is what I tried.
Consider$g(z)=f(z)-if(z)=(u+v)-i(u-v)$. Now linear combination of two entire function is entire. So $g(z)$ is entire and real part of $g$ is bounded. So $g$ is constant and hence $f$ is also constant. Am I correct? Thank you

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is entire?

Comment: @Tito Eliatron yes. I edited it.

Comment: This looks good but you need that both the real and imaginary parts of $g$ are bounded so you can say all of $g$ is bounded. Then it follows that $g$ is constant.

Comment: @John Douma I used [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229312/an-entire-function-whose-real-part-is-bounded-must-be-constant)

Comment: Then I'd say you are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

We have the identity
$$\left\vert e^z \right \vert=e^{\Re z}$$

---

Let $g(z)=(1-i)f(z)=(1-i)(u(x,y)+iv(x,y))$.

We have
$$|\exp g(z)|=\left\vert e^{(1-i)f(z)}\right\vert=e^{u+v}\le e^M$$

Since $e^{g(z)}$ is entire and bounded, by Liouiville’s theorem $$e^{g(z)}=C\implies g(z)=\text{constant}\implies f(z)=\text{constant}$$

which completes the proof.