# Given two entire functions such that $\operatorname{Re}(f(z))\le a·\operatorname{Re}(g(z))$, prove that $f(z)=a·g(z)+c$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f, g$ two entire functions such that $\operatorname{Re}(f(z))\le a·\operatorname{Re}(g(z))$.

Prove that there exists a constant $c\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=a·g(z)+c$

Is there a way to prove this that doesn't involve Liouville's theorem or any of its corollaries?

Answer (score 0):

Well, $f, g$ are entire and hence so is $f-ag$. For all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, it is given that $\operatorname{Re}(f-ag)\ge 0$. A [known corollary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229312/an-entire-function-whose-real-part-is-bounded-must-be-constant) of Liouville's theorem states that if the real part of an entire function is bounded, it is constant. Therefore $f-ag=c$ or $f(z)=ag(z)+c$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: While this does seem like the fastest approach to solve the problem, we haven't done Liouville's heorem in class yet, so I hoped to find another way to solve it (if there is one)

Comment: Oh, I missed that, sorry.
This seems weird to me, as the subject of dominance of entire functions is usually handled with Liouville's theorem.

Comment: First of all, $Re(f-ag)\leq 0$. The second point is that you show it is bounded below. How do you know that it is bounded above?