# Proving that f(z) must be constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be an entire function, if $|f(z)| < \frac{1}{|Im z|}$ then
> f(z) must be constant.

I rewrote it as $|Im z||f(z)| <1$, then I defined $g(z) = Im z \cdot f(z) $, we know f(z) is entire, but unfortunately I can not say that about g(z) since Im z ist not even differentiable. How would be best to proceed here?

(I think in the end it must be proved that $f(z)$ is 0?)

Comment: maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229312/an-entire-function-whose-real-part-is-bounded-must-be-constant

Comment: Also equation should imply - if $f$ is constant - that $f=0$