# Show that any entire function satisfying the given conditions is a constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function. Consider the set
$$S=\bigg\{re^{i\theta}: r>0, \ \frac{\pi}{4}\leq \theta\leq \frac{7\pi}{4}\bigg\}\cup \{0\}.$$
It is given that $f$ is bounded on the set $S$.
Suppose that Re$f(z)>0$ (real part of $f$ is positive) on the set $C\setminus S$. I want to show that any such function $f$ must be a constant with a positive real part.

My attempt: I know Liouville's theorem that every bounded entire function must be constant. The given function is bounded on the set $S$. Does this imply that $f$ is bounded everywhere?

I have picked many non-constant entire functions but could not find one that fulfills the given condition.

Please help which result can be applied here.

Comment: The real part of $f$ is bounded below everywhere, and you can apply https://math.stackexchange.com/q/229312/42969 to $(-f)$. – Can we close this as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes you are right.